# If $\{x\in X: f(x)>a\}$ is measurable then $\{x\in X: f(x)\geq a\}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

If $\{x\in X: f(x)>a\}$ is measurable then  $\{x\in X: f(x)\geq a\}$ is measurable

We know that  $\{x\in X: f(x)>a-\frac{1}{n}\}$ is measurable, so it is in $S$ which is a sigma algebra,

We do  $\{x\in X: f(x)\geq a\}=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x\in X: f(x)>a-\frac{1}{n}\}$? in particule why does this intersection includes $f(x)=a$?

Comment: Because if $f(x)=a$, then $f(x)>a-\frac{1}{n}$ for *every* $n$?

Comment: @Hopfeccentric why is it in the intersection? I can not assume that $f(x)=a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction 
\begin{align}
\{x\in X:f(x)\geq a\}\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{x\in X:f(x)>a-\frac{1}{n}\right\}
\end{align}
should be clear. Indeed, let $x$ be an element of the L.H.S., so that $f(x)\geq a$. Since $a>a-\frac{1}{n}$, this implies that $f(x)>a-\frac{1}{n}$ for *every* $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence $x$ is in the R.H.S. as well.

For the other direction, it would also be good to prove in the contrapositive form. Suppose $x_0$ is *not* an element of the L.H.S., so that $f(x_0)<a$. Then $\delta:=\frac{1}{2}(a-f(x_0))$ will be (strictly) positive. By the Archimedean property of real numbers, for this $\delta>0$, there exists a sufficiently big $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\delta>\frac{1}{N}$. Then it follows that
\begin{align}
f(x_0)&<f(x_0)+\delta \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(a+f(x_0)) \\
&=a-\delta \\
&<a-\frac{1}{N}
\end{align}
This shows that $x_0\notin\left\{x\in X:f(x)>a-\frac{1}{N}\right\}$, hence it cannot be in the intersection, which is the R.H.S..